# React: Load component's CSS only when component is rendered

Tags: reactjs, react-router, webpack-2, css-loader

```
# MyComponent.js

import React from 'react'
import './MyComponentStyle.css'

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   ....
}


# App.js

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import MyComponent from './MyComponent'
import PageNotFound from './PageNotFound'

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/mycomponent' component={MyComponent}/>
        <Route component={PageNotFound} />
      </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

When i go to `/mycomponent` MyComponent renders with its css. But when i go to any other url, MyComponentStyle.css still can be seen in html's Head. Is there way to render respective components CSS only when component is rendered on its route?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Webpack v2 introduced a feature called [dynamic import](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) via `import()`. You could move your CSS import into the `render` or `componentWillMount` methods, guarded by a boolean variable to ensure you only load it once.

```
import React from 'react'

let cssLoaded = false;

export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        if (cssLoaded === false) {
            cssLoaded = true;
            import('./MyComponentStyle.css');
        }

        // other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: is it still relevant in Webpack 4? OR any alternative?

Comment: not work within typescript file. it said no declaration found for scss file