# remove imported styles when component unmounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've come across a problem in my **React** app where a certain component requires a stylesheet to be loaded dynamically (when the component is mounted, it's loaded; when it's unmounted, it's removed from the page).

To my surprise, I can't seem to find anything about dynamically loaded stylesheets online or within the official **React** documentation at all. The closest thing I found to a solution was [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45560942/6425936) from 2017, and while *this solution works for mounting* the component, it doesn't remove the stylesheet once it has been unmounted.

There are always workarounds such as appending to a stylesheet from my *CDN* in the head once the component is mounted, but I want to keep as much css in one directory as I can.

The ideal solutions would be something along the lines of:

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return <div></div>;
    }
}
export default withStyles(Parent, [pathToStylesheet]);

// or... 
class Parent extends React.Component{
    componentDidMount(){ import(pathToCss); }
    componentWillUnmount(){ removeImport(pathToCss); }
    
    render(){
        return <div></div>;
    }

}
```

All help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Import CSS file as string, append stylesheet on mount and remove it on unmount

Comment: use styled-components - basically any css in js libs

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styleAsString from '!!raw-loader!../styles/MyComponent.css';

class MyComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.addStyle(styleAsString);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if(this.style) {
            document.head.removeChild(this.style);
        }
    }

    addStyle = (content) => {
        const style = document.createElement("style");
        style.type= "text/css";
        style.innerHTML = content;

        this.style = document.head.appendChild(style);
    };

    render() {
        return <div> textInComponent </div>;
    }
}
```

Import css file as string, load & unload css style manually;
Just an idea, not tested!