# How to add a Component-specific stylesheet in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

We have to print a Barcode in a 40mm × 25mm page. As React by default does not support `@media` or `@page` in the inline `style={{}}` attribute we had to add a CSS file into *that* component:

```
import "./MyComponent.css";

const MyComponent = (props) => {
    return <div>BARCODE HERE</div>
}
```

The code in `MyComponent.css` is like below:

```css
@page {
   size: 40mm 20mm;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

The problem is, this stylesheet is interfering with other components too. We tried putting this CSS inside a class, which does not work (even not for the dedicated component):

```css
/* ❌ DOES NOT WORK */
.my-component {
   @page {
      size: 40mm 20mm;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
   }
}
```

We can undo this by declaring `@page` in every other component, which will be an overkill for us.

How can we load this stylesheet only to *that* particular component?

### What have we tried so far

#### CSS Modules

As we are not doing anything with class and we've shown that, `@page` inside a class won't work, so we cannot use the CSS modules concept as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47090832/1743124).

#### Styled Components

We tried 'styled-components' like below:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div`
  @page {
    size: 40mm 25mm;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  /* other container styles */
`;

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <div>BARCODE HERE</div>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

But we failed. It's not solving the issue. The style here, even within a specified `<Container>` is intefering with other components as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight solution from React. [Here's a makeshift solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68663382/1743124) using Vanilla javascript provided by "gu mingfeng". This code will add a `<style>` tag into the `<head>` tag of the page, and then remove the tag while the component is absent (unmounted).

I'm providing the functional component approach to this solution:

```
let style:any = "";

// Instead of raw-loader we're putting our style in a string.
const BarcodeStyles = `
    @page {
        size: 39mm 25mm;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    html, body {
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
`;

useEffect(() => {
    addStyle(BarcodeStyles);

    return () => {
        removeStyle();
    }
}, []);

function addStyle(content) {
    const styleElement = document.createElement("style");
    styleElement.innerHTML = content;

    style = document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
}

function removeStyle() {
    document.head.removeChild(style);
}
```

Thanks to my colleague Mr. Harun for finding the way out and helping structuring the content.